# Is there a way to track a user thru your site pages?

Tags: php

Is there a command like getting the ip of a user that can track thru a website kinda like `$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") ;`? And anyone know of a list for them ?

Comment: google analytics.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will give you the IP of your user. And what do you mean by *a list for them*? But, why invent the wheel? What's wrong with [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/) or a similar, well-established visitor tracking system?

Comment: To answer your question(s), **yes** there is a command, and then **no** I don't know of a list, or even what that means..

Comment: You could also make a database and every time a user enters your page log the IP and the date/time, then you could have a trail.

Comment: Create a session, then assuming they don't clear cookies and you start the session on each page you could track.

Comment: IM looking to follow them like index.php to homes.php to ect.php.... within my site. I guess I can create a value of the page and insert. was looking for a easier way

Comment: And a list of available commands. like to get IP this is code $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to get Refering website its this. etc

Comment: Don't make the mistake of matching an IP to a person, you can have multiple people behind one IP.

Comment: I'm not I'm doing it by username but want a record of where they went on the site. only tracking ip to determin if they are inhouse on network or pulling from outside the network.

Comment: You can just monitor the access logs in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with chris85's comment. [Use PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) if you want to code a solution yourself. They will allow you to track users who have cookies enabled.

I would avoid IP address for this purpose because people behind a proxy (e.g: users from the same company, same university, same VPN...) will share the same IP address.

Given the function:

```
/**
 * Note this is not production code! Error checks need to be added
 */
function logVisit(PDO $db){
  static $alreadyLogged = false;
  if($alreadyLogged) return;

  /*TO DO: abort if user has Do-Not-Track header set*/

  $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $_SESSION['visit'][] = [
    'page' => $page,
    'visit_time' => $time
  ];

  $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT into tbl_log VALUES(:page, :visit_time, :session)');
  $stmt->execute([':page'=>$page, ':visit_time'=>$time, ':session'=>session_id()] );
  $alreadyLogged = true;
}
```

You could log visits for later analysis by starting your scripts with:

```
<?php
session_start();
logVisit(new PDO('...'));
```

Now, while the user is on the site, `$_SESSION['visit']` will have a record of her visit, so you could do things such as show recently viewed articles in a sidebar.  Because the data is persisted in a DB, you could analyze that for other purposes once the user leaves.

One important limitation (besides the reliance on cookies) is that it will not be easy to link up two different visits to the same user. On the plus side, it is privacy respecting because nothing as personal as IP address is logged.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for the $_Server['PHP_SELF'];